# Save TIFF from WMS layer QGIS for bhuvan lulc

Tags: qgis, wms, geotiff-tiff, bhuvan

I am new to QGIS. I was trying to export .tiff from WMS layer.

WMS URL is :

```
https://bhuvan-ras2.nrsc.gov.in/cgi-bin/LULC250K.exe
```

This WMS layer is from bhuvan for lulc data India.

```
https://bhuvan-app1.nrsc.gov.in/thematic/thematic/index.php
```

I can successfully add layer to QGIS but fail to save it as .tiff . My settings while saving TIFF file:

[image: export as tiff]

Problem is it does not create any .tiff file, even though it reports it has created a tiff. Exporting the layer as another data type (GeoPackage) to the same location works.

[image: Tiff reported as created, but no image is created]

How can I save it as .tiff and how to check what formats are supported by a WMS service ?

Comment: Have you tried checking "Rendered image"?

Comment: Yes, but still no .tiff created.

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question (it's the best way to avoid getting fewer answers than questions). If you take the [Tour], it emphasizes this.

Comment: I can both do a direct request for a Tiff, and save a tiff from the service.  so it doesn't appear to be a service issue.  Do you have permissions to write to the location you selected?

Comment: @nmtoken I am the admin so permissions should not be an issue or is it something to do explictly in QGIS ? Also I have tried saving file in different locations so it should not be the problem . Could you please provide step by step process to save .tiff.

Comment: I just requested a tiff (rather than png, jpeg... from the list of format options when first loading the layer) and saved to a temp location.

Comment: @nmtoken I had already tried that but still no tiff. I am using QGIS 3.4.1. Is there any guide or walkthrough video i can follow ? Thanks for help.

Comment: @noob, apologies, when I tested, I took that qgis said it had created the file as a fact that it had created the file, but now I see that it doesn't.  I have added a screen shot from my PC, to demonstrate I have the same problem.  Quite possibly it's a bug

Comment: @nmtoken thanks a lot. At least I can get tiff now. Will contact bhuvan regarding this export problem.

Comment: You have to set the resolution parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the output formats available by looking at the [GetCapabilities response](https://bhuvan-ras2.nrsc.gov.in/cgi-bin/LULC250K.exe?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS):

```
<GetMap>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
  <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
  <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
  <Format>application/x-pdf</Format>
  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
  <Format>image/tiff</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kmz</Format>
```

or by right clicking the layer in the browser and selecting `layer properties`.

Also the image formats that are available in the service for use in QGIS are shown in the WMS/WMTS data source manager, as below.

[image: Image encodings]

Tiff is available and selecting tiff gives you the tiff through a request like:

> https://bhuvan-ras2.nrsc.gov.in/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/mapfiles/LULC250K.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=5.604149999999999743,66.76200000000000045,37.158299999999997,98.64979999999999905&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=780&HEIGHT=771&LAYERS=LULC250K_0405&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/tiff&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

I'm not sure why the file isn't created when you export it though.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set resolution to 5 or 10 meter(project unit),extent as same as the layer,uncheck the vrt option and then you are good to go.